# How to replace Unicode Line Separator?

Tags: objective-c

I have an HTML string with some unicode line separators in it. (Hex Values E2 80 A8)

```
NSRange range = (NSRange){0,[htmlString length]};
[htmlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@"<br>" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:range];
```

How can I replace occurrences of this? The above code doesn't work.

Comment: You should be replacing `\n`, not `\r`. `\n` is a newline, `\r` is a carriage return.

Comment: Yeah already tried that. It doesn't work with the 3-byte unicode sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enter a unicode line separator (U+2028, UTF-8 E2 80 A8 as you say) in a literal string you need to use a `\u2028` unicode escape. So:

```
[htmlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2028"
                            withString:@"<br>"
                               options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                 range:range];
```

will do what you wish.

Comment: (But there is no reason for the NSCaseInsensitiveSearch option.)

Comment: @MartinR - Yes, I just copied the OP's code, it's harmless but I should have tidied it up.